# .Net core API for TLS support testing

Tags: .net, ssl, iis-7, .net-core, tls1.2

Task I'am working on right now is to create testing environment for custom HTTP Fetches.. One of the requirements for this Fetch is to support TLS 1.0-1.3.

For other, basic tests I have created .Net Core 2.0 Web API which is running on Windows Server 2008 R2, web server IIS-7.

Ideally I would love to be able just to create different end points in current API to accept required TLS, but after googling I doubt it's possible.

Mainly my question: Is there a way to test Supported TLS using single API.? Or I should create 3 different API's  with IIS configured accordingly ?

Edit:
Any solution would be helpful, meaning library's, etc.. ?

Comment: Have you read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio ?

Comment: Yes, as quick solution just gonna use sslLabs.. but as proper solution I should build socket connection, with nothing on top..

Answer (score 0):

In order to force the use of TLS for an HTTP requests, you need to rewrite the request to a HTTPS request.

You can do that for [all requests on the server](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2016/06/07/redirect-from-http-to-https-using-the-iis-url-rewrite-module/) (which is a good idea from a security/encryption standpoint), or you can modify the rewrite rules to only apply to specific requests (which you can define yourself). With the latter option, you can only target a specific subset of your API endpoints. However, I advise you to consider rewriting all requests to HTTPS, so that all traffic is TLS encrypted.